# This page can’t be displayed in IIS

Tags: iis

so im pretty new to webdev.  im trying to build a small demo project for my boss as a proof of concept.  i have built the site in VS2015 and it runs/works within the VS webhost for debugging.  im now trying to more it over to a server that was set up for this. 
here are the steps i have taken: 
1.) IIS is installed and i can see the default page.
2.) i have validated that the iis user can access the physical path.
3.) i have set up anonymous auth. 
4.) i have enabled directory browsing

here is where i start to encounter issues. when open the a browser and navigate to the address or right click the browse website option from iis manager i get *"this page cannot be displayed"*  i have looked up a couple solutions and none had worked.  the main one that was hoping for any forward progress was to go into: 
**internet option menu-> advanced  tab-> 'browsing' in the setting box -> uncheck "show friendly http error messages"**  

even with this option unchecked, im still seeing *"this page cannot be displayed"*. there was no other feedback or solutions for if the page continues to display the error.  i have tried restarting both the iis browser and the physical server all with no changes.  im hoping that someone has had this issue before and the solution is something straight forward and im missing it simply because im still new.

FILE: Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"    Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>CommonUse Web Demo</title>
<link href="App_Code/PageStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<style>
.VerticalLine 
{
border-left: thick solid #000000;
}    
th, td
{
padding: 5px;
text-align: left;
}
.TableLayoutSideBar
{
width: 200px;
}
.TableLayoutMainBar
{
width: 1000px;
}
.TBL_VerticalHeader {
    width: 75px;
}
</style>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <th class="TableLayoutSideBar">                     
              </th>
                <th class="TableLayoutMainBar">
                 <h1 style="text-align:center;">Common Use Web Demo</h1>
              </th>
                <th class="TableLayoutSideBar">                     
              </th>
           </tr>  
           <tr>
              <td class="TableLayoutSideBar">
              </td>
                <td class="TableLayoutMainBar">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                      <th class="TBL_VerticalHeader">   
                          <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Input"/>                 
                      </th>
                        <td class="TableLayoutSideBar">          
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Input Range: 0-9"/>                       
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Tbx_Input" runat="server" Width="100px"/>                             
                      </td>
                        <td class="TableLayoutSideBar">                                
                             <asp:Button ID="Btn_Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Btn_Submit_Click" />                              
                      </td>
                   </tr>  
                   <tr>
                      <th class="TBL_VerticalHeader">
                          <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Output:"/> 
                      </th>
                        <td class="TableLayoutSideBar" colspan="2">
                            <asp:Label ID="Lbl_Output" runat="server" Text="Please Input a Number"/>
                      </td>
                   </tr>                
                </table>
              </td>
                <td class="TableLayoutSideBar">
              </td>
           </tr>                
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First step is try and get a HTTP error code. Take a look at this and try and find the HTTP error code that is being generated: http://blogs.iis.net/ma_khan/troubleshooting-iis-6-status-and-substatus-codes. Sometimes opening the F12 console, going to the network tab also gives you more useful information

Comment: What is the URL in the address bar? Compare it to the sit bindings on IIS side

Comment: @LexLi, im not sure what you are asking for, when i run it out of VS2015, the address is just 'localhost:xxxx', im trying to set up the iis as 'demo.commonuse.com'  and it should default to the page '\deafult.aspx'.

Comment: @nick.mcdermaid, im not postive but it appears that im getting error 404.0.  the physical path is 'd:/commonuse/webserver', the log files are being generated on the 'c:/' drive.  do the files need to be in the same location or atleast on the same dirve?  i thought that wouldnt matter becuase the user i set up for this website has access to both location.

Comment: also when going into the 'f12 console -> networking tab' nothing is appearing back, forward, refresh, etc... nothing is writing to this tab.

Comment: so i think i just figured out my own problem... im trying to set up a address to soon...  i just removed 'demo.commonuse.com' from the binding and now it is coming up just fine.  thank you for everyone's help.  this problem was because of my own stupidity/new-ness.

Comment: You're only stupid if you don't learn from your mistakes! Well done fixing it

Comment: @mmp786 post that as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, thanks for the that.  its fun but frustrating to learn new things.

Comment: Wait till you learn javascript. yikes!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i have figured out my own problem... im trying to set up an address to soon. i removed 'demo.commonuse.com' from the binding and now it is coming up just fine. aka because i haven't set up a domain for it, thus it needs to use the machines IP as the address instead. thank you for everyone's help.